# MySQL stored procedure not working from ajax/php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in MySQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bancos_remove`(IN `id`
INT, IN `cb` INT) 
BEGIN    
    DECLARE nomban VARCHAR(50);    
    DECLARE cuanban INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE codigo CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';   
    DECLARE mensaje VARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE respuesta VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE texto VARCHAR(512);
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN
         GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
            codigo = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            mensaje = MESSAGE_TEXT;
         SET respuesta = CONCAT(codigo,' - ',mensaje);
      END;    
    SELECT nombre INTO nomban FROM bancos WHERE idbancos = cb;  
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cuanban FROM bancos_cuentas WHERE idbancos
= cb;    
    IF cuanban > 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '90000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Banco tiene Cuentas Asociadas';    
    ELSE
      DELETE FROM bancos WHERE idbancos = cb;
      IF codigo = '00000' THEN
         SET texto = CONCAT(cb,' - ',nomban);
         CALL log_int_add(id, 'Mantenimiento de Bancos', 'B', NULL, texto);
      ELSE
         IF (mensaje IS NOT NULL) THEN
            SET texto = CONCAT('Intentó Borrar:',cb,' - ',nomban,' Error:',codigo,'-',mensaje);
            CALL log_int_add(id, 'Mantenimiento de Bancos', 'B', texto, NULL);
         END IF;
      END IF;    
END IF;    
SELECT respuesta;
END
```

I invoke said procedure from PhP as follows:

```
$getparams = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);
$output = go($connect, "CALL bancos_remove(".$_SESSION['idusuarios'].",".$getparams['c'].")");
```

`Edit:` The "go()" function in PhP looks like so:

```
function go($connection, $statement){
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $statement);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $output = $row['respuesta'];
    return $output;
}
```

And finally, the PhP script is called from jQuery in the following code:

```
$.get("../app/probancos.php",{a:3,c:$("#txtIdBanco").val()},function(data){ ... some code ...});
```

Now, when using the $.get() method, and therefore filtering the INPUT_GET values, everything works dandy.  BUT when invoking the very same code, but using the $.post() method in jQuery and thus using the values filtered from INPUT_POST, I get the error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

And of course, the whole code is not executed.  Therefore the question would be: Why does this code work with GET but not with POST?  I would prefer to use POST to avoid exposing the values passed to the back-end application if possible (please tell me if I'm mistaken).  Thank you in advance for your response(s).

Comment: Have you confirmed that data is sent using POST from AJAX? Have you confirmed that `$getparams` is populated correctly?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it by printing the "formed" statement in Php, and the data is passed correctly.

Comment: Sorry, a bad term ... I meant that once the data is passed to PhP I echoed the $statement variable to see its contents, and the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with stored procedures because if you catch sent data properly and pass it to the procedure properly there is no way that it does not work - additionaly you've confirmed that it works with GET method.

As Jay Blanchard said, you have to check how the dataset is passed and if it passed at all.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that the data is passed correctly.  I also included in the edit the function go() which executes the call to the db procedure.